# How to get correct resolution for UI elements in different screen size devices using Unity?

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, canvas

I tested app in two devices that is in **iPhone 7 plus** and **iPad Pro 10.5"**.I iPhone 7 plus the image looks ok but in iPad pro it looks stretched.The canvas settings are given in the image below.[image: Canvas Settings]

**How to adjust my canvas settings or other settings to show UI correctly for different screen resolutions?**

Comment: I think you need to change that `width---------height` slider to be all the way at one end or the other.

Answer (score 0):

Set the "Screen Match Mode" to "Expand". or you can use "Aspect Ratio Fitter" component by adding it to your canvas.